# How make a login system using ajax without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do is make a login system without refreshing the page using a `button`, ajax but i dont know how to do it.

My problem is my code wont work if i click the button. How do i use ajax to communicate with my myIncludes.php if i press the button login?

index.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#login').click(function(){
<?php include_once('myIncludes.php'); ?>
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">    
Username: <input type="text" name="user" /><br />
Password: <input type="text" name="pass" /><br />
<button type="button" name="login" id="login">Login</Button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

myIncludes.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');
include_once('user.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $object = new User();
    $object->Login($user, $pass);
}
?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
class User{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function Login($user, $pass){
        if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $user);
            $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st->execute();

            if($st->rowCount() == 1){
                echo "User verifies, Access granted";
            } else {
                echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Please enter Username and Password";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
class Connection{
    public function dbConnect(){
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', '');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is your AJAX? You use a PHP include statement inside a JavaScript click handler, that is not going to work. The PHP file will be included when the page is rendered, not when you click the button.

Comment: plain-text passwords are not the way to go...

Comment: There are [lots of tutorials](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ajax+tutorials+login+using+php&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=nlyMU5LwDozBuATKoYCABw) out there. Also lots of Q&A in SO itself. How about learning something and making an effort to do it by your own..?.

Comment: Too many issues here to resolve as one question. It appears you are trying to do too many things that are above your experience level all at once. Try to narrow this down to smaller issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently building a system like this, but to know how to do this you must understand AJAX. First of you need an HTML page with a filled header, but an empty body you only need some empty divs in the body.

```
<?php 
//start up some objects and sessions if required
//I like to set up some data and add this data to a session.
//so its available to the entire application. In an object oriented way.
?>
<html>
   <head>
      //fill in some header data like imports etc.
      <script src="your javascript file"  type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src ="jquery"/></script>//I dont use it myself but it can be useful 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="content"></div>
      <div id ="hidden" style="visibility:hidden></div> //for hidden js feedback.
      <script type="text/javascript">
          loadLogin();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then your javascript (without jquery)

```
URL = "urltoyourbackendphp";

//type is type of function to be called by php.
//div is div to be changed.
//vars is array with post variables.
function ajaxcall(type, div, vars){
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();     //doesnt work on IE 7 or lower
    xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xml.readyState==4 && xml.status==200){
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xml.responseText;
        }
    };
    xml.open("POST",URL,true); //URL to php
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var nvar = "type="+type;
    var i = 1;
    foreach(vars as vara){
        nvar = nvar+"&var"+i+"="+vara;
    }
    xml.send(nvar);
}

function login(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
    name = name.value;
    pass = pass.value;
    ajax(login, hidden, array(name, pass));
}

function loadLogin(){
    ajax("loadpage", "content", array("login"));
}

function loadHome(){
    ajax("loadpage", "content" array("home");
}

function alertLogin(){
    alert("Username or Pass were wrong");
}
```

and your php backend

```
<?php
$type = $_POST["type"];
if($type == "loadpage"){
   $pagename = $_POST["var1"];
   if($pagename == "login"){
       fread("loginpage.php"); //echoes the contents of a file
   }elseif($pagename == "home"){
       fread("Home.php");
   }
elseif($type == "login"){
   $name = $_POST["var1"];
   $pass = $_POST["var2"];
   //do checks on these. Make sure to prevent sql-injections too.
   if(checks){
      echo "<style onload='loadHome()'></style>";
   }else{
      echo "<style onload='alertLogin()'></style>";
      //This is one of the few ways to make php do another javascript call.
      //Via echo and I think it might as well be the most efficient.
   }
}?>
```

Now there might be a few syntax errors since this is mostly out of my head without a compiler to check this for me, but its the system I use and it works really fine plus it can be really dynamic. But if you want a bigger application you must keep in mind all sorts of things like preventing sql-injection and sessions etc.

The most important thing to know is that I did base most of this on the w3schools tutorials about ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
ndex.php
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#login').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // data send format POST/GET
                url: "./myIncludes.php", // file url for data processing 
                data:  $("#frm_data").serialize(), // all form field are serialize  
                dataType: "json", // response type xml, json, script, text, htm
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.result == true){
                        window.location = "dashboardpage.php";  
                    }else {
                        alert("invalid user/password");
                    }
                }
            });
           });            
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="form" id="frm_data" >
Username: <input type="text" name="user" /><br />
Password: <input type="text" name="pass" /><br />
<button type="button" name="login" id="login">Login</Button>
</form>
</body>
</html>


myIncludes.php
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');
include_once('user.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $result = false;
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $object = new User();
    if($object->Login($user, $pass)){
        $result = true;
    }else{
        $result = false;    
    }
     echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
    die();
}
?>





 user.php
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
class User{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function Login($user, $pass){
        if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $user);
            $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
            $st->execute();

            if($st->rowCount() == 1){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Include jQuery library to login page.

Follow the below script to do ajax login action:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#login").click(function() {
   var postData = $("form").serialize();
   jQuery.ajax({
     'url': 'myIncludes.php',
     'data': postData ,
     'type': "POST",
     'success': function(data){
       if (data == true) {
         // Logged in successfull
         alert("user loggedin successfully");
         window.location = "dashboardpage.php";
       } else {
         alert("invalid user/password");
       }
     }
   });
 });
});
```